# Elasticsearch multiple values match without analyzer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Pardon my knowledge on ElasticSearch. I have an Elasticsearch collection which has documents like these:

```
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 2,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Coimbra District"

    }
}
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 1,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Federal District"        
    }
}
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 1,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Masovian Voivodeship"
    }
}
```

These 3 json documents are indexed in the ES server. I haven't provided any analyzer type (and don't know how to provide one either :))
I am using spring data Elasticsearch and executing the following query to search for the docs with region 'Masovian Voivodeship' or 'Federal District':

```
{
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "Masovian Voivodeship OR Federal District",
    "fields" : [ "dimensions.region" ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting it to return 2 hits. However, it returns all 3 docs (probably due to 3rd one having district in it). How can I modify the query so that it can perform the EXACT match and only provide 2 documents? I am using following method:

```
QueryBuilders.queryString(<OR string>).field("dimensions.region")
```

I have tried `QueryBuilders.termsQuery`, `QueryBuilders.inQuery` and `QueryBuilders.matchQuery` (with array) but no luck.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html try set default_operator to AND. Or make your query "Masovian AND Voivodeship OR Federal AND District"

Comment: Hi, I tried with query `{
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "Masovian AND Voivodeship OR Federal AND District",
    "fields" : [ "dimensions.region" ]
  }
}` but it didn't return any hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do here.

To start, I set up an index without any explicit mapping or analysis, which means the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used. That's important since it determines how we can query against the text fields.

So I started with:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 2,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Coimbra District"

    }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 1,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Federal District"        
    }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/3
{
    "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 1,
    "dimensions": {
        "region": "Masovian Voivodeship"
    }
}
```

Then I tried your query and got no hits. I don't understand why you have `"dimensions.ga:region"` in your `fields` parameter, but when I changed it to `"dimensions.region"` I got some results:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "Masovian Voivodeship OR Federal District",
         "fields": [
            "dimensions.region"
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.46911472,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.46911472,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "value": 1,
               "dimensions": {
                  "region": "Masovian Voivodeship"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.3533006,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "value": 1,
               "dimensions": {
                  "region": "Federal District"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.05937162,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "value": 2,
               "dimensions": {
                  "region": "Coimbra District"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

However, this returns a result you don't want. One way to fix that is as follows:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "(Masovian AND Voivodeship) OR (Federal AND District)",
         "fields": [
            "dimensions.region"
         ]
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.46911472,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.46911472,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "value": 1,
               "dimensions": {
                  "region": "Masovian Voivodeship"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.3533006,
            "_source": {
               "date": "2013-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
               "value": 1,
               "dimensions": {
                  "region": "Federal District"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Another way would to do it (I like this one better) which gives the same results is to use a combination of [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and [boolean should](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "dimensions.region": {
                     "query": "Masovian Voivodeship",
                     "operator": "and"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "dimensions.region": {
                     "query": "Federal District",
                     "operator": "and"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/bb5062a635c4f9519a411fdd3c8540eae8bdfd51

Comment: Hello @Sloan, first of all, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I tried your 3rd solution (because I also think it is better approach) and worked like a charm! The only thing I was missing was `operator`. I was not specifying `operator` and hence, it was taking default operator while generating the query. The default is OR hence, it was searching bu tokens with OR and that's why I was getting 3 results (and even you got 3 results in the first attempt by running the same query). I have removed the 'ga' part from query as it was a typo. Again, cheers for the solution :)

Comment: The example in sense it's great!